# Network environment switch with Wifi network change

Tags: network, wifi, monterey

I have two network environments I want to set up, with one having Wifi enabled but not connected, while the other is connected to a Wifi network. While I can configure whether Wifi is enabled or not, it looks like you can't configure which Wifi network to configure in a network environment.

So the configurations I want to have are:

- `Ethernet only`: Ethernet interface enabled with DHCP, Wifi interface enabled but **not** connected to network. That last part is important and is what I struggle with.
- `Wifi only`: Ethernet interface disabled, Wifi enabled and connected to a specific network.

My goal is to be able to quickly change between these two setups. But if I switch between these two environments, I always need to manually connect/disconnect the Wifi network as the environment does not remember my preference here.

Is there a way to do this with macOS tools or third-party helpers?

(System is macOS 12.3 Monterey.)

Comment: This could be scripted with `networksetup` or you might be able to use the older [ControlPlane](https://github.com/dustinrue/ControlPlane) utility.

Comment: @da4: Thanks for the suggestion, using shell tools is certainly a good option for me. But it looks like `networksetup` does not support _disconnecting_ from a Wifi network, and joining doesn't work on my system, either: `Error: -3912  The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.wifi.apple80211API.error error -3912.)` (that code corresponds to `kCWChallengeFailureErr`; it doesn't matter whether I pass the password or let it get it from keychain, unfortunately).

Comment: So the error turned out to be a temporary problem, a reboot fixed it. Still leaves the problem of _disconnecting_ from a Wifi network.

Comment: `networksetup -setairportpower <device name> off` won't do it?

Comment: @da: Interesting, `-setairportpower` off and then on again does indeed not auto-connect to the last connected network and thus seems to do what I want. I didn't try it before since I though it behaves the system settings do. Now I just need to script all that. Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @da4 I now have a working solution.

Switch to Wifi location and join network:

```
#!/bin/bash

networksetup -switchtolocation "Wifi"

# Get all Wi-Fi interfaces (it should be just one).
WIFI_INTERFACES=`networksetup -listallhardwareports | sed -n '/Wi-Fi/{n;s/^.*:[[:space:]]*//;p;}'`

for INTERFACE in $WIFI_INTERFACES ; do
        networksetup -setairportnetwork $INTERFACE "network" "password"
done
```

Switch to ethernet location with Wifi interface enabled but not connected to a network:

```
#!/bin/bash

networksetup -switchtolocation "Ethernet"

# Get all Wi-Fi interfaces (it should be just one).
WIFI_INTERFACES=`networksetup -listallhardwareports | sed -n '/Wi-Fi/{n;s/^.*:[[:space:]]*//;p;}'`

for INTERFACE in $WIFI_INTERFACES ; do
        networksetup -setairportpower $INTERFACE off
        sleep 1
        networksetup -setairportpower $INTERFACE on
done
```